# How to get all the image links from all anchor tags in CKEditor 5

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x, ckeditor5

I'm new to CKEditor 5 and been looking for a way to get all the image paths from all anchor tags and placed it in an array in a CKEditor 5 instance.

What I want to achieve is, I want to get all the paths and compare it to the ones in the database. And if the name of the image is missing then I'll delete the image on the database so that it will not be loaded after saving.

I've been trying to solve this but unfortunately, I haven't had answers or even hints for it yet. I've read the documentation but I can't understand some of it.